# TP-Link Router Configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

This is the network configuration in our building.(Below Linked Image)

Computer 1 , Computer 2, and Computer 3 and Wifi router D are connected to switch using wired ethernet.

Laptop D1 and Laptop D2 are behind Wifi router D and connected wirelessly to Wifi router D.

Computer 1 , Computer 2, and Computer 3 can see and communicate with each other.

I am trying to figure a way to also include Laptop D1 and Laptop D2 in the LAN so that they can communicate with other computers(Computer 1,Computer 2 etc.)

I can connect Laptop D1 directly to switch instead of wifi router but i require both the laptops to be connected to LAN so that we can share files faster using LAN instead of Internet.

[image]

Edit:
Lets Say
Computer 1 and Computer 2 can access a certain shared folder on Computer 3 by typing 192.168.0.103\sharedfoldername . Also they can see each other in Network Places in windows.

My Question is, how can I configure my Wifi router D and Laptop D1 and Laptop D2 so that they can access that shared folder by typing the same address i.e 192.168.0.103\sharedfoldername.

On Network Places in Laptop D1 only Laptop D2 and router are visible. I would like to see other computers too.

Comment: thanks for the details Antony but what's the question ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The illustration is great, but we need to know what have you already tried. How is router D configured vs the switch?

Comment: Because you only have a single router and a switch this should be trivial... The router ("D") is your DHCP server, DNS server and Internet gateway for your LAN... All you need to do is connect the switch to one of the LAN ports on the router and all the connected devices will be able to obtain IPs from the router... the wireless is built in to the router so these will be on the same subnet and DHCP pool as the LAN devices so you shouldn't have ANY problems connecting your devices via wifi or Ethernet and they should all be able to communicate. You'll need to configure firewall/sharing etc.